# What DbContext project do I get to work with EF?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm new to entity framework.  I've got EF 4.2, from NuGet.  Now I'm hearing it would be good to get DbContext.  I've got into the extension manager and tried finding it, but I see about 8 there.  Which is the "righ" one?  I don't know if this matters but I use both C# and VB.NET.  Also, I don't know if this matters or not, but I'm using a data-first model, not a code-first or model-first models, for doing EF development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your EDMX design surface, right-click and pick `Add Code-Generation Item`:

[image]

Pick the ADO.NET DbContext Generator from the online gallery:

[image]

This adds two T4 template files (`*.tt`) in your solution explorer, and generates the `DbContext` and the entity classes for you:

[image]

And this is the resulting class derived from `DbContext` for your own project:

[image]

Comment: I must not have that, because I don't have ADO.NET DbContext Generator in my installed gallery sellections.

Comment: @Rod: there's an `Online Templates` to pick from on the left hand side of that dialog (towards the bottom) - in there, you should be able to search (and find!) that `ADO.NET DbContext Generator` and install and use it!

Comment: I got the ADO.NET DbContext Generator, and installed it (thanks!) Now, when I right click to add the code generation item, I get a security warning message that says, "Running this text template can potentially harm your computer. Do not run it if you obtained it from an untrusted source."  Not very comforting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can trust the source you obtained the DbContext template from ;)