# Using DBSet property in an edmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

In my MVC project, I'm using 'Ado.Net entity Data Model' (.edmx) and I've created it by Add--> new --> Data --> 'Ado.Net entity Data Model' from an existing database (I mean it's not 'Code First' nor 'Model First' Approach) but I want to take advantage of 'Defining sets on a derived context DbContext with DbSet properties' like what explained in this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx) :

```
public class UnicornsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UnicornModel> Unicorns { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrincessModel> Princesses { get; set; }
}
```

and use: `DBSet<ModelName>` instead of `DbSet<tableName>`
Is there any way to do that? Which file must be changed?

Comment: This SO post that explains how to generate a DbContext class from your .edmx might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040396/what-dbcontext-project-do-i-get-to-work-with-ef

Comment: @tdykstra, Thanks , I know how to generate POCO classes, but what I'm looking for is how to use MVC Models in DbSet and take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could I think it would be the wrong approach. Either create a code first, or reverse engineer an existing database into a code first model with the 'entity framework power tools' or simply add new entities to your edmx via the visual designer (as in design the new ones from scratch). Personally I would reverse engineer your existing database and get the great new EF 4.3 code migrations feature.

Comment: Thanks, I can convert my .edmx to CodeFirst using POCO calsses but I'm trying to use MVC Models in DBSets in order to access to more properties. A good sample to it is Jabbr (https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR/blob/master/JabbR/Models/JabbrContext.cs) which use the Models in DbContex file (with no comment unfortunately)

Comment: Can you show us one of the mvc model classes and the entity from your edmx that is closest to the model class and explain what you are trying to achieve? Is your model class containing some fields from the entity and then additional fields that don't map to the database?

Comment: @JulieLerman, Thanks for your attention. The following class in my Models is like the 'ChatMessage' table :  public class ChatMessage
    {
        [Key]
        public int Key { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }        
        public virtual ChatRoom Room { get; set; }
        public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset When { get; set; }
    } but my 'chatmessage' table doesn't have 'Room' propery of type of this model. So the 'Room' in my Model does not map to any field in my .edmx entity Data Model

Comment: Amir, you tagged this MVC as well. Is your goal to display "Room" only in your view (not for editing) ? Otherwise whats your relation between ChatMessage and room? If there actually is a relation, why not consider creating a foreign key from ChatMessage into your Room table named for example RoomId ?